# Button delay Highlighting

Tags: ios, button, delay, selected

I'm building an iOS application and I have some buttons inside a PageView Controller inside a ContainerView. The problem is the buttons aren't responsive at all. They only get selected some time after I pressed them.

Is there any fast solution?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the click event is not firing for all buttons? Or do they fire when they feel like it?

Comment: They only get highlighted if I press them for sometime. I want them to highlight right when I press them.

Comment: I realised it's the PageView Controllers fault. Still don't know how to solve it tho.